# Replace Part of File Name Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have files that are generated every morning:

- Default_20140227_05.00.29.csv
- Default_20140226_05.00.29.csv

I would like to rename the files:

- VOD_20140227_05.00.29.csv
- VOD_20140226_05.00.29.csv

I would basically be replacing `Default` with `VOD`.

I am using Powershell 1.0.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 62):

simplified:

```ps
ls *.csv | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace "Default","VOD"}
```

Comment: works like a charm. However please note that `-replace` treat search parameter value as regex expression so you have to use special regex characters for certain values, like `\s` to find and replace the space char

Comment: On Mac (and it will likely be the same on Linux), I had to use `gci` rather than `ls` likely because `ls` is a native command.

Comment: This gave an error for me. I ended up using the approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43090430/13762264)

Answer (score 23):

I do not have PowerShell 1.0 to test, but assuming you are running this in the folder where files reside, you can try:

```
Get-ChildItem Default_*.csv  |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '^Default','VOD'}
```

Answer (score 7):

`gci | ?{$_.Name -like "Default*"} | % {$newname = ([String]$_).Replace("Default","VOD"); Rename-item $_ $newname}`

A more explanatory version:

```
$DefaultFiles =  Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Default*"}
ForEach($File in $DefaultFiles) 
{
    $newname = ([String]$File).Replace("Default","VOD")
    Rename-item -Path $File $newname
}
```

Comment: Care to add any explanation? I don't get the impression that the poster has the ability to necessarily parse/maintain that. I drop in "it works, but I don't have a clue how" isn't much better than not knowing.

Comment: It seems pretty self explanatory if you know the commands, I shouldn't have been using the aliases or pipelining I guess.. But then again I tend to put as much effort into my answers as the asker does the question... updated anyways

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a generic version that will take your find and replace as parameters and log out what you've renamed (handy, imo), here's one building from Cole9350's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22182551/5472558):

```
$Find = $args[0]
$Replace = $args[1]
$TargetFiles =  Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*$Find*"}
ForEach($File in $TargetFiles) 
{
    $newname = ([String]$File).Replace($Find,$Replace)
    write-host "Renaming $File to $newname"
    Rename-item -Path $File.PSPath $newname
}
```

And if you want it recursive, just add `-Recurse` after `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, but it says '$Find' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I made a "test.cmd" file with your code, and get the error when running the file from a powershell prompt, and when I drag a folder and drop it on the test.cmd file (what I'm wanting to achieve), it just briefly flashes a cmd window with no renaming taking place.

Comment: Simple fix for ya @nollaf126 . This code is written using Powershell, so you'll want a `.ps1` extension for your file, not `.cmd` - that should fix your error. 
You'll also need to provide two arguments so if the file is called `rename.ps1` and you want to rename `Hat` to `HeadSock`, you'll need execute `rename.ps1 Hat HeadSock`